# Template function for casting multiple number of params

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, variadic-templates, template-meta-programming

I'm trying to write a template function that will perform a set of `dynamic_casts()` based on its template parameter. I've got the following to illustrate:

```
class FooData
{
public:
    virtual ~FooData() {};
};
class DerivedFooData: public FooData{};
class Other: public FooData{};

void bar(DerivedFooData* d1, DerivedFooData* d2) {}
void bar(DerivedFooData* d1, Other*, DerivedFooData* d2, Other*, Other*) {}


int main()
{
    DerivedFooData d1,d2;
    std::vector<FooData*> container1{&d1, &d2};
    std::vector<FooData*> container2{&d1, &d2};

    // I want bar to be called with container1[0] cast to DerivedFooData and container2[1] cast to DerivedFooData 
    // the first two template params are each container size

    foo<1, 1, DerivedFooData, DerivedFooData>(container, container2);

    // I want bar to be called with
    // container1[0] cast to DerivedFooData
    // container1[1] cast to Other
    // container2[0] cast to DerivedFooData
    // container2[1] cast to Other
    // container2[2] cast to Other
    foo<2, 3, DerivedFooData, Other, DerivedFooData, Other, Other>(container, container2);
}
```

I can manually create some of those:

```
template <int N, int M, typename U, typename V>
void foo(const std::vector<FooData*>& input, const std::vector<FooData*>& output) 
{
    bar(dynamic_cast<U*>(input[0]), dynamic_cast<V*>(output[0]));
}

template <int N, int M, typename U, typename V, typename W, typename X, typename Y>
void foo(const std::vector<FooData*>& input, const std::vector<FooData*>& output) 
{
    bar(dynamic_cast<U*>(input[0]), dynamic_cast<V*>(input[1]), dynamic_cast<W*>(output[0]), dynamic_cast<X*>(output[1]), dynamic_cast<Y*>(output[2]));
}
```

But I can't figure out how to specify in a generic way all combinations of `N` and `M`. I assume variadic templates will come in somewhere, but I would need some guidance.

Comment: Can you explain what the `N` and `M` arguments are supposed to control?

Comment: N and M would be the size of the first and second parameter vectors (input and output in foo()s)

Comment: FWIW, if you are using `dynamic_cast` you generally have a design flaw.  If you are going to use it you really should check the return value to make sure it is not `nullptr` otherwise you're going to open yourself up to undefined behavior.

Comment: If `N` and `M` are the size of the vectors, and they have to be known at compile time, why are you using `std::vector` and not `std::array`?

Comment: @NathanOliver agreed, on cast, just trying to keep the minimal example small :-)

Comment: @cdhowie the larger program in which this need arose justifies the vector. And even if it were a bad decision, well, the API is vector. But good point, once I have the solution working for vectors I'll consider a change

Comment: Strictly C++11 or also C++14 and C++17 feature are allowed?

Comment: @max66 any of the three (i'm assuming anything before 11 would be extremely convoluted and 20 is too recent)

Comment: @Jeffrey - OK: added a C++14 answer (but also an example of a C++20 simplification)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basic idea behind any template recursion is to handle the arguments one at a time, recurse on the function with one input type argument removed, and then terminate when the template argument list is empty.

A common way to handle two variadic type lists is to define a "pack" type that you can specialize on, where the pack takes a variable number of template arguments.  This gives you the ability to easily separate multiple sets of variadic type arguments.

Here, I demonstrate this example by declaring `type_pack` without any implementation (which is fine, we only use it as a type and we never instantiate it) and then I declare multiple specializations of `foo_fn` that are designed to:

- Peel the first type off of one of the two lists and perform the `dynamic_cast`.
- Determine the next step by removing the first type argument to the relevant pack type.
- Transition to the second pack when the first one becomes empty.
- Pass the processed (cast) arguments through to the next step.
- Finally, call `bar()` with the computed arguments when both packs are empty.

```
template <typename...>
struct type_pack;

// Base declaration that we will specialize.
template <int, int, typename, typename>
struct foo_fn;

// Specialization handling when the first pack is not empty.
template <int OffsetA, int OffsetB, typename THead, typename... T1, typename... T2>
struct foo_fn<OffsetA, OffsetB, type_pack<THead, T1...>, type_pack<T2...>> {
    template <typename... Args>
    static void f(foovec_t const & input, foovec_t const & output, Args && ... args) {
        return foo_fn<
            OffsetA + 1,
            OffsetB,
            type_pack<T1...>,
            type_pack<T2...>
        >::f(input, output, std::forward<Args>(args)..., dynamic_cast<THead *>(input[OffsetA]));
    }
};

// Specialization handling when the first pack is empty and the second
// pack is not empty.
template <int OffsetA, int OffsetB, typename THead, typename... T>
struct foo_fn<OffsetA, OffsetB, type_pack<>, type_pack<THead, T...>> {
    template <typename... Args>
    static void f(foovec_t const & input, foovec_t const & output, Args && ... args) {
        return foo_fn<
            OffsetA,
            OffsetB + 1,
            type_pack<>,
            type_pack<T...>
        >::f(input, output, std::forward<Args>(args)..., dynamic_cast<THead *>(output[OffsetB]));
    }
};

// Specialization handling the terminating case (all packs empty).
template <int OffsetA, int OffsetB>
struct foo_fn<OffsetA, OffsetB, type_pack<>, type_pack<>> {
    template <typename... Args>
    static void f(foovec_t const &, foovec_t const &, Args && ... args) {
        bar(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }
};

// Helper type to provide the two initial integer values.
template <typename, typename>
struct foo;

template <typename... T1, typename... T2>
struct foo<type_pack<T1...>, type_pack<T2...>> {
    static void f(foovec_t const & input, foovec_t const & output) {
        foo_fn<0, 0, type_pack<T1...>, type_pack<T2...>>::f(input, output);
    }
};
```

You would call this like `foo<type_pack<DerivedFooData, Other>, type_pack<DerivedFooData, Other, Other>>::f(container, container2)` in your second example.  Note that you don't have to provide any sizes; these are inferred from the size of each pack.

See [this demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/036bdd6cd6aa476a) and note that the pointer arguments where the type doesn't match come through as null.

I don't attempt to define `bar()` as I assume you have already done this, or know how to do it.  The `bar()` in my example only accepts specific pointer types (for the purposes of testing that the casts were correctly performed).

This code uses only C++11 features.

---

Note that `std::forward` is not strictly necessary because the cast values are always pointers.  However, it's good to get in the habit of using it when forwarding a variable-size argument list.  If the values were huge strings/vectors then forwarding at each step would eliminate a ton of useless copying.

Answer (score 3):

Not elegant at all (and not sure about the exact indexes) but... something as follows (given that you can use C++14) should works (if I understand correctly what do you want)

```
template <std::size_t Dim1, typename ... Ts, std::size_t ... Is>
void foo_helper (std::index_sequence<Is...>, std::vector<FooData*> inV,
                 std::vector<FooData*> outV)
 { bar( dynamic_cast<Ts*>(Is < Dim1 ? inV[Is] : outV[Is-Dim1])... ); }

template <std::size_t Dim1, std::size_t Dim2, typename ... Ts>
void foo (std::vector<FooData*> inV, std::vector<FooData*> outV)
 { foo_helper<Dim1, Ts...>
      (std::make_index_sequence<Dim1+Dim2>{}, inV, outV); }
```

I know that C++20 is too recent for you but, just for fun, I show you how use the new C++20 lambda-template feature to avoid the use of the helper function

```
// from C++20: foo_helper() isn't needed anymore
template <std::size_t Dim1, std::size_t Dim2, typename ... Ts>
void foo (std::vector<FooData*> inV, std::vector<FooData*> outV)
 { [&]<std::size_t ... Is>(std::index_sequence<Is...>)
    { bar( dynamic_cast<Ts*>(Is < Dim1 ? inV[Is] : outV[Is-Dim1])... ); }
      (std::make_index_sequence<Dim1+Dim2>{}); }
```

The following is a full compiling C++14 example

```
#include <vector>
#include <type_traits>


struct FooData { virtual ~FooData() {}; };
class DerivedFooData: public FooData { };
class Other         : public FooData { }; 

void bar (DerivedFooData*, DerivedFooData*) {}
void bar (DerivedFooData*, Other*, DerivedFooData*, Other*, Other*) {}

template <std::size_t Dim1, typename ... Ts, std::size_t ... Is>
void foo_helper (std::index_sequence<Is...>, std::vector<FooData*> inV,
                 std::vector<FooData*> outV)
 { bar( dynamic_cast<Ts*>(Is < Dim1 ? inV[Is] : outV[Is-Dim1])... ); }

template <std::size_t Dim1, std::size_t Dim2, typename ... Ts>
void foo (std::vector<FooData*> inV, std::vector<FooData*> outV)
 { foo_helper<Dim1, Ts...>
      (std::make_index_sequence<Dim1+Dim2>{}, inV, outV); }

int main ()
 {
   DerivedFooData d1, d2, d3;
   std::vector<FooData*> container1 {&d1, &d2};
   std::vector<FooData*> container2 {&d1, &d2, &d3};

   foo<1, 1, DerivedFooData, DerivedFooData>(container1, container2);

   foo<2, 3, DerivedFooData, Other, DerivedFooData, Other, Other>
      (container1, container2);
 }
```

Comment: Clever use of `std::index_sequence`, I like it.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer "pack type" syntax instead of give extra numbers, so

```
foo<std::tuple<DerivedFooData, Other>, std::tuple<DerivedFooData, Other, Other>>
```

instead of your:

```
foo<2, 3, DerivedFooData, Other, DerivedFooData, Other, Other>
```

You can still do:

```
template <typename Tuple, std::size_t ... Is1, std::size_t ... Is2, typename ... Ts>
void foo(std::index_sequence<Is1...>, std::index_sequence<Is2...>, Ts&&...args)
{
    foo<std::tuple<std::tuple_element_t<Is1, Tuple>...>,
        std::tuple<std::tuple_element_t<sizeof...(Is1) + Is2, Tuple>...>>(
            std::forward<Ts>(args)...);
}

template <std::size_t N1, std::size_t N2, typename ... Ts>
void foo(const std::vector<FooData*>& input, const std::vector<FooData*>& output)
{
    static_assert(N1 + N2 == sizeof...(Ts), "!");
    foo<std::tuple<Ts...>>(std::make_index_sequence<N1>{},
                           std::make_index_sequence<N2>{},
                           input,
                           output);
}
```

to use your syntax.

Now using a primary helper to cast each vector element inside a `tuple`

```
template <typename Pack> struct dynamic_cast_as_tuple;

template <typename ...Ts>
struct dynamic_cast_as_tuple<std::tuple<Ts...>>
{
    template <typename T>
    std::tuple<Ts*...> operator ()(const std::vector<T*>& v) const
    {
        return (*this)(v, std::index_sequence_for<Ts...>{});
    }

private:
    template <typename T, std::size_t ... Is>
    std::tuple<Ts*...> operator ()(const std::vector<T*>& v, std::index_sequence<Is...>) const
    {
        return {dynamic_cast<Ts*>(v[Is])...};
    }
};
```

And then, wanted function is:

```
template <typename pack1, typename pack2>
void foo(const std::vector<FooData*>& input, const std::vector<FooData*>& output)
{
    std::apply([](auto*... ps){ bar(ps...); },
               std::tuple_cat(
                   dynamic_cast_as_tuple<pack1>{}(input),
                   dynamic_cast_as_tuple<pack2>{}(output))
        );
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/aJ1YZQ)

`std::index_sequence` is C++14 and `std::apply` c++17, but can be implemented in C++11.